# How to add global commands to Jest like describe and it?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm writing a little testing tool for Jest (just to learn). It is called `assertTruthy(msg, fn, args)`, expects a message, a function and arguments and should pass if the thing that is returned when the function is invoked with the arguments is truthy and fail if its not.

I would like to add it to Jest, so that you could call it without importing it in every environment.

```
describe('someFn()', () => {
  // like 'it', 'describe' and 'expect' it should just be available here
  it('is a function', () => {
    expect(typeop someFN).toEqual('Function');
  });

  assertTruthy('it should return true', someFn, 3, 4);
});
```

I know Jest has [`setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array) and `setupFilesAfterEnv` but I can't figure out how to use them to achieve this.

How do you add commands to Jest?

**PS:** On a single project basis ([in CRA](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests/)) I managed to do this like this:

```
// in src/setupFiles.js
const assertTruthy = // function definition ...
global.assertTruthy = assertTruthy
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Add global functions to Jest

In order to add global **functions** to jest, you need to define `setupFiles` in your configuration and attach that function to the global object in the setup file:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/setupFile.js'],
  // ...
};
```

so if you want to do something very similar to `it`, I would suggest you do something like this:

```js
// /setupFile.js

// in order to change an existing function (not youre case):
global.it = function(description, fn) { /* ... */ };

// this is how you define a new function globally
global.assertTruthy = (message, func, ...args) => {
  return global.it(message, () => {
    expect(func(...args)).toBeTruthy();
  });

// optional: implementing the same interface as `jest.It`
```

### Supporting the same interface as `jest.It`

Here's an example from the **Airbnb** library [`airbnb/jest-wrap`](https://github.com/airbnb/jest-wrap/blob/master/index.js#L125) where they wrapped the describe function. If you want to implement the `jest.It` interface, you'll also need to implement `assertTruthy.todo`, `assertTruthy.skip`, `assertTruthy.only`, & `assertTruthy.each` ([check out the `it` interface](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jest/index.d.ts#L301)). `todo` and `skip` are pretty easy since you want to do exactly the same as the original ones.

For `each` & `only`, we need to change the `it` function inside our implementation. A simple way to support `only` is by using a closure and passing the correct `it` function from the closure's inpu. `each` can be a little more complex to implement.

```js
// /setupFile.js

// normaly, use the jest `it` function
global.assertTruthy = assertTruthyCreator(it);

// bypass for todo and skip
global.assertTruthy.todo = global.it.todo;
global.assertTruthy.skip = global.it.skip;
// only calls the same function but uses `only` internaly
global.assertTruthy.only = assertTruthyCreator(it.only);
// special case which needs special implementation
// see usage below
global.assertTruthy.each = assertTruthyCreator(it.each, true);

function assertTruthyCreator(itFunc, withTable) {
  if (withTable) {
    return (message, func, ...args) => {
      return itFunc(args)(message, (...caseArgs) => {
        expect(func(...caseArgs)).toBeTruthy();
      });
    };
  }

  return (message, func, ...args) => {
    return itFunc(message, () => {
      expect(func(...args)).toBeTruthy();
    });
  };
}

// usage:
assertTruthy.each(
  'add numbers',
  (a, b) => a + b,
  [2, 4],
  [4, 5],
  [7, 9]);
```

### How to use in test files

If you're using typescript for writing jest test, the first thing you'll need to do is `declare` your new function somewhere:

```ts
interface IGenericFunction {
  (...args: any[]): any;
}

declare const assertTruthy: (message: string, func: IGenericFunction, ...args: any[]) => any;
```

With javascript, you can skip that step.

After that, just use it like you use `describe` and `it`:

```js
const funcToTest = (a: number, b: number) => a + b;

describe("Test Suite", () => {
  assertTruthy('this ran with assertTruthy', funcToTest, 5, 3);

  test("another test", () => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

and jest will treat this as any other `it` function
[image: jest run results]

### Using as a `node_module` dependency

If you want to create a library from this, you can basically just pass a `node_modules` path to the `setupFiles` array.

For example, with [this](https://github.com/kibibit/jest-utils) repository, you can do as follows:

1. Install using `npm install --save-dev @kibibit/jest-utils`
2. Add the following to your **jest configuration**
3. Use the function as described above

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  setupFiles: ['node_modules/@kibibit/jest-utils/lib/jest-utils.js'],
  // ...
};
```

and it should work the same as importing it locally.

Comment: Thank you! I can award you the bounty in 22 hours 

Comment: @J.Hesters your welcome! glad to help! :-) I added more information since I noticed you also asked how to do this across multiple projects

Comment: @thatkookoooguy Thank you very much. If you'd be so kind, could you also provide an example how to add `.skip` or `.only` to `assertTruthy`? I'm struggling with this ever since I read your answer :)

Comment: I did it like this: `assertTruthy.skip = { // ... call it.skip }` would you say that is a good implementation?

Comment: @J.Hesters yeah, that's perfect. for `skip` and `todo` you can easily just use the original ones. `each` and `only` might need a bit more work. I'll add that to my answer as well

Comment: how can one add types for assertTruthy?

Comment: @bboydflo You can have `jest-utils.ts` instead of the javascript fie, and compile that file to javascript with types. then, you should have typings for it.