# How to test if a wrapper in Jest calls skip and it correctly?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

This is a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174883/how-to-add-global-commands-to-jest-like-describe-and-it).

I have a function called `assertTruthy` for Jest. `assertTruthy(msg, fn, args)`, expects a message, a function and arguments and should pass if the thing that is returned when the function is invoked with the arguments is truthy and fail if its not.

I want to extend it to also support Jest's `only` and `skip`.

Here is what I wrote:

```
assertTruthy.skip = ({
  message = '',
  fn = undefined,
  args,
} = {}) => {
  it.skip(message, () => {
    expect(fn(args)).toBeTruthy();
  });
};

assertTruthy.only = ({
  message = '',
  fn = undefined,
  args,
} = {}) => {
  it.only(message, () => {
    expect(fn(args)).toBeTruthy();
  });
};
```

How would I test these functions?

Here is what I tried, which works, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

```
describe('skip()', () => {
  test('it skips the function', () => {
    it.skip = jest.fn();
    assertTruthy.skip({
      message: 'something',
      fn: () => true,
      args: undefined,
    });
    expect(it.skip).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a fair enough test that your `assertTruthy` `skip` and `only` call Jest's `it` `skip` and `only` methods.

You might want to assert that it also calls them with the arguments you expect using `toHaveBeenCalledWith`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate more, what you want to achieve and I did't get it properly why you want to extend jest skip and only methods to achieve the same thing that you are already testing.

But if you only want to test if a function not been invoked/executed with `toHaveBeenCalledTimes()` based on the arguments to be truthy/falsy then you are doing it right.